# React: confusion about the usage of `useRef` here for storing the previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw this custom hook when reading some blog post

```js
const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return ref.current;
};
```

I made a codesandbox to experiement with it https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-surf-eenqo?file=/src/App.js

and indeed it works. It preserves the previous input value I had there.

And I tried to replicate this hook using `useState`

```js
const usePrevious2 = (value) => {
  const [prevValue, setPrevValue] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setPrevValue(value);
  }, [value]);

  return prevValue;
};
```

However the value returned by `usePrevious2` is in sync with the current state. I wonder what is the underline mechanism for the differences here? Why is that the `ref` can preserver the previous state but not another `useState`. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The second implementation using state will trigger a re-render when its state updates. You're seeing the updated state catch up with the value just "cached".

Answer (score 1):

The issue with using `useState` here is that state updates result in re-renders.

If you use `usePrevious` / `useRef` and change the input, there will be *one* state update, when the input value changes - and after that state update occurs, the `usePrevious` will shortly schedule a `ref.current = value` assignment, but such assignment will not cause a re-render.

In contrast, with `usePrevious2` / `useState`, when you use `setPrevValue`, a re-render will occur. When the input field changes, there will be 2 re-renders; one when the input field changes, and then another after the `useEffect` callback runs and calls `setPrevValue`. So the `usePrevious2` will only be "out of date" for a very short time, until its effect hook runs and sets the state again.